# ROC/AUC Confidence Interval

Tags: confidence-interval, statistical-power, roc, auc

For a single ROC curve (with relevant AUC score), how can you calculate the confidence interval?  (The data used to generate this ROC/AUC is available)

Given my relatively limited background in this area, this would be a case of 'the easier, the better'.

PS: please also inform me of any conditions that have to be fulfilled (if required by the formula you would use to calculate the CI).

Comment: are you looking for code? Many of the packages that make ROC curves also compute the CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for code? Many of the packages that make ROC curves also compute the CI. If you are using R look at the [pROC](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/pROC.pdf) package.

For theoretical derivation see
Receiver Operating Characteristic Curve Confidence Intervals and Regions
Kerekes, J.
IEEE Geoscience and Remote Sensing Letters, April 2008, Vol.5(2), pp.251-255 [Peer Reviewed Journal]

Comment: Thanks Benjamin!  I used MATLAB and LibLinear (not my choice, I was told to use them)

Comment: Is there any library for python?